# Data structures and algorithm (DSA)

Tags: coding-style

I am a beginner and I am trying to get through the topics of DSA which topics are important and on which all parts I should focus on.

Array, stack and flow, Trees

Comment: Start with easy to understand structures like (associative) Arrays, Stacks (aka LIFO) and Pipes (aka FIFO). Work on them until they don't have secrets any more. Then have a look at single and double linked lists before you look at Trees. Of course, any author of a book on data structures is right; just follow the text.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

**Firstly you need to start from basics such as:**

1. Array
2. Pointers
3. Linked List

**After learning the basics go for**

1. Stack
2. Queue

**And at last go for**

1. Tree
2. Binary Search Tree
3. Graph
4. Hash